# JS onclick only works the first time

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am new to JS. I am creating a button and I want the button to toggle what it says. I can get it to fire once, but then it won't fire again unless i refresh the page.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure its simple.

JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fullscreen(){
            var elem = document.getElementById("button1");
            if (elem.value=="Maximize"){
                elem.value = "Minimize";
            }else {
                elem.value = "Maximize";}
        }
</script>
```

in the body of the page is:

```
<div>    
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Minimize" onclick='fullscreen()'>
</div>
```

What I expect is the text of the button will switch when the variable is passed through the if statement.  I can get it to change from "minimize" to "maximize" onclick, but the second click does nothing.

Comment: seems to be running perfectly

Comment: Works for me too.  Have  you confirmed your `fullscreen` function is being hit?  Maybe stepping through will explain what is messing with it.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal interesting, I cannot get it to toggle back.

Comment: Run it on jsfiddle

Comment: @IrkenInvader yes I put an alert in it in different places and it pops upthe first time and not a second.

Comment: @Darw1n34 check the "Maximize" spelling exactly

Comment: Are you getting any error in console on second click?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i did put alert and your code is working fine. You can even see this in your developer console. Also you should put === instead of == for comparing to string.
There should be other problem i think.

```
         function fullscreen(){
            var elem = document.getElementById("button1");
            if (elem.value ==="Maximize"){
              alert('hi');
                elem.value = "Minimize";
            } else {
              alert('hello');
                elem.value = "Maximize";}
            }
```